# How to replace values in df that are NOT fulfilling condition

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, negate

I am trying to clean my data and can't find a way to replace values that are not according to my conditions like in the following example:

```
df1<-  data.frame(
A=c("a","b","c"),
Ch=c("c1","xyz","c2"),
val=paste0("x",1:3),  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

all values that are different than c1, c2 I want to change into "other".

I tried:

```
for( i in 1:length(df)
if (df[i,2]==c1 | c2){
stay same vaue?!?
} else df[i,2] <- "other"
```

which did not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it does what you need it to do :)

Answer (score 3):

For replicability:

```
df1<-
tibble(
  A=c("a","b","c"),
  Ch=c("c1","xyz","c2"),
  val=paste0("x",1:3)
)
```

If you are trying to do it across all columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1%>%mutate_all(list(~ifelse(.=="c1"|.=="c2",.,"other")))
```

Base R solution:

```
data.frame(
sapply(
  df1,
  function(x)ifelse(x=="c1"|x=="c2",x,"other")
 )
)
```

Comment: In base R, you can just do `df1[df1!="c1" & df1!="c2"] <- "other"`, assuming that those columns are strings and not factors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R solution if you want to change only one column

```
df1<-  data.frame(
A=c("a","b","c"),
Ch=c("c1","xyz","c2"),
val=paste0("x",1:3),  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

`df1$Ch[df1$Ch!="c1" &  df1$Ch!="c2"] <- "other"`

This will replace the column Ch only